# values not being returned for the button array

Tags: php, arrays, input

I have $_POST array of submit buttons, hiddens, cbo's and texts and when i loop through the array after post, it only returns the last of the array regardless of what isset.

already tried isset and then looping through the array

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $body .= "$<input type='text' name='txtOTHER_INCOME_AMT' value='" . 
                $row['INCOME_AMT'] . "'>                                                                                 
            <input type='submit' name='cmdUpdateIncome' value='Update'>                                                                                                                                  
            <input type='hidden' name='income_id' value='" . $row['INCOME_ID'] . "'>";
    $i++;
}

//check and see if the user is trying to update an OTHER INCOME
if ($_POST['cmdUpdateIncome'] != "" && $_POST['updateincome_id'] != "") {
    for ($i=0; $i>count($_POST['cmdUpdateIncome']); $i++){
        if (isset($_POST['cmdUpdateIncome'])){
                   //do some stuff
        }
    }   
}
```

if the user clicks the 3rd of n buttons, I want to grab the values for these fields from the form that correlate to the button that was selected:

txtOTHER_INCOME_AMT & income_id (key from the database so that i can UPDATE it based on what was supplied in txtOTHER_INCOME_AMT).

A `print_r($_POST)` gives

```
[cboOTHER_INCOME_TYPE_CODE] => Array ( 
        [0] => F4 
        [1] => F1 
        [2] => M3 
        [3] => F2 
        [4] => F9 
        [5] => 41 
        [6] => F7 
        [7] => TL 
) 
[txtOTHER_INCOME_AMT] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1007.07 
        [1] => .01 
        [2] => 1326.02 
        [3] => 502.36 
        [4] => 10001.03 
        [5] => 150.77 
        [6] => 100.22 
        [7] => 500.44 
) 

[cmdUpdateIncome] => Array ( 
        [0] => Update 
) 
[income_id] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 6 
        [2] => 7 
        [3] => 8 
        [4] => 9 
        [5] => 10 
        [6] => 11 
        [7] => 13 
)
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Maybe you should show us the HTML form, it would help us understand the question

Comment: i inherited this and don't have the time to re-code this badboy...is the mysql vs. mysqli the reason that the $_POST array would fail?

Comment: No almost definitely not

Comment: Looks like you are putting out multiple inputs with the same name in the same `<form>`. Did you try `name='income_id[]'` etc to make them into arrays?

Comment: just tried that and....nope....still grabbing the data from last item in the array.  it's like it's not even looking through the other 12 items that are being rendered on the form...weird stuff...i'm sure i'm just too close to this and missing something simple.  ugghh!

Comment: Can you show us a `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: It would also be useful to see the HTML you output for the `<form>`

Comment: form: <form name='frmWebApp' method='post' action='blahblah.php'>

Comment: No the whole HTML from `<form....>` to `</form>` and in your question, its so much easier for us to read it if its nicely formated

Comment: [cboOTHER_INCOME_TYPE_CODE] => Array ( [0] => F4 [1] => F1 [2] => M3 [3] => F2 [4] => F9 [5] => 41 [6] => F7 [7] => TL ) [txtOTHER_INCOME_AMT] => printr:  Array ( [0] => 1007.07 [1] => .01 [2] => 1326.02 [3] => 502.36 [4] => 10001.03 [5] => 150.77 [6] => 100.22 [7] => 500.44 ) [cmdUpdateIncome] => Array ( [0] => Update ) [income_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 [4] => 9 [5] => 10 [6] => 11 [7] => 13 )

Comment: **readable** - In the question. **not readable** in a comment

Comment: [cboOTHER_INCOME_TYPE_CODE] => Array ( [0] => F4 [1] => F1 [2] => M3 [3] => F2 [4] => F9 [5] => 41 [6] => F7 [7] => TL )

Comment: [cmdUpdateIncome] => Array ( [0] => Update )

Comment: [income_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 [4] => 9 [5] => 10 [6] => 11 [7] => 13 )

Comment: [txtOTHER_INCOME_AMT] => Array ( [0] => 1007.07 [1] => .01 [2] => 1326.02 [3] => 502.36 [4] => 10001.03 [5] => 150.77 [6] => 100.22 [7] => 500.44 )

Comment: i believe the issue is that there is only one item in the cmdUpdateIncome $_post array...therefore it is only looping through the check one time and hitting $i=0 everytime...it is only updating the first cbo & text because it never gets past the first element in the array....bullocks!  wondering how i can tell it which cmdUpdateIncome button was clicked because they are all named "Update" by design.  thoughts?

Comment: hey riggs...fyi - i abandoned using the cmd button array and used a simple for loop and affixed and _$i on the back of every button...used a hidden to value the unique ID from the table and then simply looked for the $_post value in the button...fixed it.  would have like to use the button array long-term but needed to fix the sucker and move on....thanks for your comments, man.  cheers!